Complexity of this function
I would like to know how to properly determinate the complexity of this function :
let rec fact n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> 1
  | n -> n * fact (n - 1)

let biggest_factorial_below n =
  let i = ref 1 in
  while (fact !i < n) do
    i := !i + 1;
  done;
  !i

After some reflection, i found that the complexity might be O(log(n)^2).
Can you tell me if it's true or wrong?
I tried to use the Sterling approximation to find the biggest I to have i! > n ,so I find that i is  proportional to log(n). I know that fact(n) is O(n) so O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(i) = O(i^2)) so the complexity is O(log(n)^2).
(Sorry for my English, I'm not native)

As a sidenote, biggest_factorial_below can be more efficient by not completely recalculating factorials on each loop iteration.

Your analysis is correct, but not tight, in that you could give a better bound: using the Sterling formula, one can derive that the inverse factorial function is O(log n/log (log n)).  Hence, the maximum i you'll reach is O(log n/log (log n)), and therefore, the total complexity is, indeed, O((log n)²/(log (log n))²).
